# How do I solve 405 error, when I'm using Heroku and Strapi?

Tags: heroku, deployment, strapi, http-status-code-405

I'm using Heroku to deploy my backend and Vercel for the front end, (Next.js & Strapi project).
The application has been deployed for a few months, and never had any issues. When I work on it on my localhost everything ran smoothly as well, but today I started getting error 405 even though I didn't change anything in terms of fetching for data. The only answers that I was able to find in google regarding this issue are only related to when the request URL isn't right, but that's not the case.[result that I get in my Network section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfnXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file "Procfile" to your folder, and write inside this. It's necessary to Heroku run your script.

```
web:yourscript.js
```

Replace yourscript with your script.